# Android Studio claims this class is abstract but I didn't write it to be abstract?

Tags: java, android

I am following a tutorial I found at http://www.androidauthority.com/android-game-java-785331/

I just wanted a basic tutorial to get me started making games on android. 
Here is the MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(new GameView(this));
    }
}
```

**Here is the Class Android Studio is claiming as abstract:**

```
public class MainThread extends Thread {

    private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
    private GameView gameView;
    private boolean running;
    public static Canvas canvas;

    public MainThread(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, GameView gameView) {

         super();
         this.surfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;
         this.gameView = gameView;

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

      while (running) {

        canvas = null;

        try {
            canvas = this.surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
            synchronized(surfaceHolder) {
                this.gameView.update();
                this.gameView.draw(canvas);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {} finally {

            if (canvas != null) {
                try {
                    surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
      }
    }

    public void setRunning(boolean isRunning) {
         running = isRunning;
    }

}
```

And Here is the class that is attempting to instantiate the "abstract" class:

```
public class GameView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    public MainThread thread;

    public GameView(Context context) {
       super(context);
       getHolder().addCallback(this);
       thread = new MainThread(getHolder(), this);
       setFocusable(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

    }

    @Override
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        thread.setRunning(true);
        thread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {

        boolean retry = true;
        while (retry) {
           try {
              thread.setRunning(false);
              thread.join();
           } catch (InterruptedException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
          retry = false;
        }
    }

    public void update() {

    }

}
```

I copied and pasted all the code from the tutorial. The only thing I can think of is the super class? or if there was a button I accidentally clicked when creating the class that made it abstract? I'm not sure what's wrong but I can't continue with the tutorial with errors. If anyone can see what's wrong or can maybe recommend another Android Studio Game tutorial I would very much appreciate it.

Comment: What is the message you're getting exactly?  You could try changing the code until it "works", e.g. change MainClass so it doesn't extend Thread.  Or try creating another class that extends Thread and see if it thinks that is also abstract.

Comment: When I hover over the line: thread = new MainThread(getHolder(), this); I get a red message that says : 'MainThread' is abstract; cannot be instantiated. I will try your suggestions and see if I can get it working. Thank you.

Comment: I tried making another class called SecondThread and copying the code over and it worked, no more red lines. Odd I guess naming it MainThread for some reason caused it to be considered abstract.

Comment: Is there another different class also called MainThread that you were accidentally importing?

Comment: That might be what happened. The studio makes it so easy to import stuff, it's easy to accidentally import the wrong thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a problem with the naming. I had the exact same problem and merely changing it to 'GameThread' solved the problem